# why does my beer batter seem to hold too much oil?

Tags: deep-frying

Please can you help find out why when i deep fry my cod in beer batter it even when drained on paper is still full of cooking oil please.
I use same measure of flour to beer and add lemon juice and saffron for colour .

Comment: Beer batter is generally a bit oily, what result were you expecting? Are you comparing it to another you have had?

Comment: What oil and at what oil temperature are you deep frying? Also are you sure you are not overloading, which will reduce the oil temperature?

Answer (score 4):

I've found that when my oil is not hot enough to seal what I'm cooking immediately, the batter picks up a lot of oil. The same thing happens if I batter something frozen and then let it sit for a minute or two before it goes into the fryer.

Answer (score 0):

Temp of oil should be 375. Otherwise the food absorbs too much oil. In most cases you want the food at room temperature before frying.  Remember that introducing the food will lower the temp so always go 10 degrees above desired cooking temp and don't overcrowd the pan. Best way to test oil is to drop a small amount of batter into oil to check that it  rises and begins cooking immediately. A piece of white bread can also be used.